# Colorize landscape-sysinfo

Tags: bash, landscape

Any ideas where the base scripts for landscape-sysinfo are? I would like to add some custom colors. For example, when RAM is between 0 and 50%, color the percentage green, 50-70% color yellow, etc. I Tried looking in /usr/bin/landscape-sysinfo and I'm not finding anything that I can add some bash to. Suggestions on locations?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

They are python based.  /usr/bin/landscape-sysinfo opens up a python library:

```
from landscape.sysinfo.deployment import run
```

Which is located under:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/landscape/sysinfo
```

But, you will probably have a difficult time "just adding color" here as the package will be updated from time to time wiping out your changes.  But feel free to mess around with it. :)

Note this package is completely open source and housed in the [landscape-client source code](https://launchpad.net/landscape-client).  It's installed with the 'landscape-common' package onto your system.

If you just want to modify the message you see printed out, there are a lot of ways to do that, and these are great starting points:

- [How do I edit the ssh motd?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23246/how-do-i-edit-the-ssh-motd)
- [How set the Message of the Day (MOTD) as Ubuntu Server?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/385072/how-set-the-message-of-the-day-motd-as-ubuntu-server)
- http://www.howtogeek.com/104708/how-to-customize-ubuntus-message-of-the-day/